# html5 composite operations in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas

I have read some blogs and questions/answers about this issue, but most of them are out of date, so I am looking for the current situation.

I am working on a project where I need to composite the resultant images from others by composition.

On my work-machine, Windows7 with FX 17.0.1, it works as I expect. Even on IE9 most of the time it works fine, but I have appreciated composite operations are not always taken.

On my boss-machine, Windows Vista SP2 + IE9, it works unpredictability ... sometimes it renders the whole composition, sometimes only one of the images, sometimes none, ...

From this analysis:
http://weblog.bocoup.com/canvas-in-ie9-too-good-to-be-true/

I deduced I can't work with composite operations because the audience of the site, but I continue searching and I see composite operations well documented at ie developer site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

So, what is the current state of these operations support?

I need the application with full functionality over:

- Internet Explorer 9
- Firefox 20
- Chrome 30
- Opera 12
- Safari 5

I will appreciate any clarification on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

PS.- the main code I need to do with composite operations is:

**EDIT: If you see I can do this better and this behavieur could be becasue the way I've written the code, I'll appreciate hints to improve it.**

```
$.fn.buildScooter = function(canvas, ctx, scoPath, supPath, sustPath, colourPath) {
    var supImg   = '';
    var sustImg  = '';
    var paintImg = '';
    var scoImg   = new Image();
    scoImg.onload = function() {
        if (supPath !== '') {
            supImg = new Image();
            supImg.onload = function() {
                sustImg = new Image();
                sustImg.onload = function() {
                    ctx.drawImage(scoImg, 0, 0, canvas.width , canvas.height);

                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
                    ctx.drawImage(supImg, 0, 0, canvas.width , canvas.height);


                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
                    ctx.drawImage(scoImg, 0, 0, canvas.width , canvas.height);


                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
                    ctx.drawImage(sustImg, 0, 0, canvas.width , canvas.height);

                    if (colourPath !== '') {
                        paintImg = new Image();
                        paintImg.onload = function() {
                            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
                            ctx.drawImage(paintImg, 0, 0, canvas.width , canvas.height);
                            jQuery().showScooter();

                        }
                        paintImg.onerror = function() {
                            jQuery('#messages').html('<p style="color:red;">No hay imagen disponible: </p><p style="color:white">' + paintImg.src + '</p>');
                            jQuery().showScooter();
                        }
                        paintImg.src = colourPath;
                    } else {
                        jQuery().showScooter();
                    }
                }
                sustImg.onerror = function() {
                    jQuery('#messages').html('<p style="color:red;">No hay imagen disponible: </p><p style="color:white">' + sustImg.src + '</p>');
                    jQuery().showScooter();
                }
                sustImg.src = sustPath;
            }
            supImg.onerror = function() {
                jQuery('#messages').html('<p style="color:red;">No hay imagen disponible: </p><p style="color:white">' + supImg.src + '</p>');
                jQuery().showScooter();
            }
            supImg.src = supPath;

        } else {
            ctx.drawImage(scoImg, 0, 0, canvas.width , canvas.height);
            if (colourPath !== '') {
                paintImg = new Image();
                paintImg.onload = function() {
                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
                    ctx.drawImage(paintImg, 0, 0, canvas.width , canvas.height);
                    jQuery().showScooter();
                }
                paintImg.onerror = function() {
                    jQuery('#messages').html('<p style="color:red;">No hay imagen disponible: </p><p style="color:white">' + paintImg.src + '</p>');
                    jQuery().showScooter();
                }
                paintImg.src = colourPath;
            } else {
                jQuery().showScooter();
            }
        }
    }
    scoImg.onerror = function() {
        jQuery('#messages').html('<p style="color:red;">No hay imagen disponible: </p><p style="color:white">' + scoImg.src + '</p>');
        jQuery().showScooter(canvas);
    }
    scoImg.src = scoPath;
}
```

**EDIT II:**

Following Ken suggestion I've updated the code to (the simplest case)

```
function myHandler() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('scooter-canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.clearRect (0 , 0 , canvas.width , canvas.height);

    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width , canvas.height);
    jQuery().showScooter();
}

$.fn.buildScooter = function(scoPath, supPath, sustPath, colourPath) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = myHandler;
    img.src = scoPath;

    if (img.complete) myHandler().bind(img);
}
```

But the image is still rendered sometimes.

jQuery().showScooter() just remove an overlay layer and shows canvas element with an animate opacity.

```
$.fn.showScooter = function() {
    jQuery('#scooter-canvas').css('display', 'block');
    jQuery('#scooter-canvas').css('opacity', 0);
    jQuery('#scooter-canvas').animate({
        opacity: 1,
    }, 400, function() {jQuery('#overlay').remove();});
}
```

**EDIT 4:**

It's strange that if I added an else sentence to (img.complete) condition, I get always this message, but myHandler is fired.

```
function myHandler() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('scooter-canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.clearRect (0 , 0 , canvas.width , canvas.height);

    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width , canvas.height);
    console.log(this.src + ' drawed');

    jQuery().showScooter();
}

$.fn.buildScooter = function(scoPath, supPath, sustPath, colourPath) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = myHandler;
    img.src = scoPath;

    if (img.complete) myHandler().bind(img);
    else console.log('No se ha completado la carga: ' + img.src);
}
```

And the image is rendered sometimes and I have no clue how to get the reason.

```
REGISTRO: no se ha completado la carga http://cfg.scooter.dev.inetpsa.com/img/3PSCO/1P/Pictures/D/Background/3PSC1PD2TB01A010_ZZZZZZZZ_0PAL0RFC_001_01.png 

REGISTRO: http://cfg.scooter.dev.inetpsa.com/img/3PSCO/1P/Pictures/D/Background/3PSC1PD2TB01A010_ZZZZZZZZ_0PAL0RFC_001_01.png drawed
```

Comment: I never tried it with IE9 but...did you take a look on excanvas.js?

Comment: Yes, I added it and same results. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE has problems (bug) with `onload` which isn't always triggered if the image exist in the cache.

To detect this on IE you must use the `complete` flag of the image and if true call your handler that way instead. Simply re-factor the image onload handler code to a non-anonymous function:

```
img.onload = myHandler;
img.src = url;

if (img.complete) myHandler().bind(img);

function myHandler() {
    ...
}
```

The `bind` makes sure the context (`this`) will be the image as with `onload`.

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks ... that makes sense to the trouble I am in ... but unfortanetally the images is still rendered sometimes. Please take a look to my last edit where I have added the code following your hint.

Comment: Finally things go better adding some meta tags for controlling cache, since I think it was a memory thing ... Btw, I am using your Script to preload images, so i am sure all situation are taken. thanks @Ken